# How can I set the FindReplace box in VBA to allow Word Document editing while the box is still active?

Tags: vba, ms-word, find-replace

I'm trying to code some routines in VBA for Word that use regular expression to search for certain elements in documents. I got this code (please disregard for now that it's coded using Selection, it's just a mock-up to see if the workflow is sound):

```
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
End With
With Selection.Find

    .Text = "[0-9]{5,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute
End With
If Selection.Find.Found = True Then
    Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show
End If
```

and it works in the sense that it does find 5+ digit numbers. However I would like the user to have the ability to edit the found number or any other part of text while the box is still active, to continue to search once the editions are finished. I'd be grateful for any tips on how to solve this issue.

Comment: To have that dialog exposed to the user, I believe you would need to use SendKeys, which is 'flaky.'

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Charles. Unfortunately, it did not solve the issue in the sense that it does bring up the replace window, but it immediately disappears, because there are consecutive searches in the sub. I would like the window to persist until the user closes it with "Cancel" yet still being able to edit the document with the window present.

Comment: @Michael - that additional information should have been part of your question. How do you expect anyone to answer when you only provide half the relevant information? So, to answer your question, what you want is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you will get is to use your code to set the Find parameters and then execute the Find dialog button, as shown below.

```
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting

    .Text = "[0-9]{5,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("FindDialog")
```

This will leave the user to press Find Next to get the first match but will allow the dialog to work as normal, enabling edits.

Comment: Thank you Timothy, but unfortunately this as well does not work. It displays the window for a brief moment, closing it immediately before going to the next search.

Comment: @Michael - then you must be doing something else besides what is in the code in my answer. In my testing it works exactly as expected. There isn't another option to display a modeless dialog.

Comment: when I use your code as standalone sub it works are you described. I wish to however incorporate it in a series/chain of searches, and as soon as I get to this step, the sub immediately goes through it, without waiting for the user to press cancel, just goes straight to the next search that has Diaglogs.Show. One possible solution, tho not ideal, would be to move the code you provided to the end of the sub, as the last step.